# Pegar resultado da próxima linha

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá! Estou trabalhando em um guia de séries e estou querendo criar um botão de avançar, no caso quando for clicado, ele ir pro próximo episódio...

Na tela existe um botão de avançar que seria pra mudar de episódio. Só quero que quando eu clicar, automaticamente ir pro próximo episódio, fiz um select mas não sei se tá certo.

A url dele está assim:
perfil.html?titulo=Stranger_Things&episodio=04

Select:

```html
$titulo = $_GET['titulo'];
$episodio = $_GET['episodio'];

$sql = "select * from episodios join series on episodios.mid = series.id where series.titulo='$titulo' and episodios.episodio > '$episodio' order by episodios.episodio DESC limit 1";
```

Comment: Se for o proximo episodio acho que o resultado da sua consulta devia ser ordenado em ordem crescente: `episodios.episodio ASC limit 1`

Comment: Você chegou a testar a query? Se sim, te retornou algum erro?

Comment: Consegui aqui. Respondo eu mesmo a pergunta do que eu fiz?